# Change to RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write this condition simpler using RegExp?

```
if (current === '+' || current === '-' || current === '*' || current === '/')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `current` is always one character,

- regex

  ```
  if (/[+*/-]/.test(current))
  ```
- ES6, no regex

  ```
  if ('+*/-'.contains(current))
  ```
- non-ES6, no regex

  ```
  if ('+*/-'.indexOf(current) !== -1)
  ```
- non-ES6, no regex, short

  ```
  if (~'+*/-'.indexOf(current))
  ```

if not,

- regex

  ```
  if (/^[+*/-]$/.test(current))
  ```
- ES6, no regex

  ```
  if ([...'+*/-'].contains(current))
  ```
- non-ES6, no regex

  ```
  if (['+', '*', '/', '-'].indexOf(current) !== -1)
  ```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to escape the `/`?

Comment: Seeing `current` is always compared to one character by the OP, I think we can assume it will always be one. I wonder what would be more performant though, with or without `^` and `$`. Nice addition for the ES6 variant too.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Not inside a character set.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(/[+*/-]/.test(current)){
      //do something
     }
```

Escape these charcters as they have special meaning in regular expression.

Comment: Syntax error and String.prototype.test does not exist.

Comment: In a character, class, none of those characters has a special meaning except `-`, which only has a special meaning if it's not the first character in the character class.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I mixed perl with js thankyou for correcting

Comment: Your regex now has an out-of-order range in it: `+` through `*`, which throws a SyntaxError. If it were `*-+`, it wouldn't throw the syntax error, but wouldn't match `-`. You *do* need to escape `-` if not in the first or last position of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You use a *character class* and the `test` function of regular expressions:

```
if (/^[-+*/]$/.test(current)) {
    // ...
}
```

Note the `^` and `$` assertions (beginning and end of input), so that `"-+"` won't match.

Example:

```js
var rex = /^[-+*/]$/;
["p", "+", "-", "-+"].forEach(function(current) {
  console.log(current, rex.test(current));
});
```